# Conditional Countifs Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, count, formula, countif

enter image description here[image]

So basically on (Column Team) I have a "Talaga & Burot" and on (Column Status) i have "On Time & Slow"
Countif are not working, What I want to be done is, I can count how many slow and on time burot have, and how many slow and on time talaga have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the 'Team' column is column A and the 'Status' column is column B, you can try

```
=query(A2:B, "Select A, count(A) where A <>'' group By A pivot B", 0)
```

Change range to suit and see if that works for you?

[image]

### Reference

- [Query()](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/)

Comment: its on different tab but same google sheet

Comment: Then, add the sheetName before the range. E.g:  'Sheet1'!A2:B

Comment: Most welcome @JhonWalterBitangcol ! Glad to hear I was able to help.